# Change Field Properties of custom field in custom object

Tags: custom-object, custom-field

What I want to do is I have a custom object and its Page Layout with its fields. At the time of creation of custom field I forget to make it read only. I want to change it read only but while Editing that filed again I am not able to make it read only. As you can see There is check box for making it read only but it is not editable .[image: Custom field]

I tried another way ,editing Field properties from Page layout from there also field is Read only field is not editable.[image: Custom filed properties as you can see Here is option of making it read only but it also not editable.]

Can any one suggest me another way of doing it? I know another way ,delete this filed and create again with read only properties But I don't want to delete it because it is used somewhere else.

Comment: why is this field required ?If required then  you cant make it read only .Remove required to make it read only

Comment: Because I want this field value whenever record for this object is created .I also want that anyone can't modify this field. Is it because I made it required ?

Comment: Yes .Remove required and see if it helps and for this requirement i think you need to make it required plus add validation so that no one edits the field

Comment: @Mohith So it is not possible to make field required which means it is must to provide its value while creating a record and make it read only on its layout

Comment: @vj1207 - How do you expect the user to enter a value of a required field if you are able to set it to read only???? If you are populating the value using code or workflows, it is your responsibility to ensure the proper workflows / triggers are in place to populate it. The next question I would ask is how are you populating the field

Comment: @Eric I am populating it by Code.